# How can I create an "update" form in Symfony 4?

Tags: forms, symfony, sql-update, formbuilder

With this form I want to update my database entry:

myController.php

```
  public function index($id, $slug, Request $request, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder)
  {

      $item = new User();

      $item= $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(User::class)->find($id);
      $form = $this->createFormBuilder($item)
      ->add('username', TextType::class, array('attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')))
      ->add('email', EmailType::class, array('attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')))
      ->add('is_active', HiddenType::class)
      ->add('plainPassword', RepeatedType::class, array('type' => PasswordType::class,'invalid_message' => 'The password fields must match.','options' => array('attr' => array('class' => 'password-field')),'required' => true,'first_options'  => array('label' => 'Passwort', 'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')),'second_options' => array('label' => 'Passwort wiederholen', 'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')),))
      ->add('cancel', ButtonType::class, array('label' => 'Cancel','attr' => array('class' => 'cancel form-btn btn btn-default pull-right close_sidebar close_h')))
      ->add('update', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Update','attr' => array('class' => 'form-btn btn btn-info pull-right','style' => 'margin-right:5px')))
      ->getForm();
      $form->handleRequest($request);

     if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entityManager->flush();
            return $this->redirectToRoute('pages', array(
              'slug' => $slug,
            ));
      }
      return $this->render('form.html.twig', ['form' => $form->createView()]);

}
```

form.html.twig:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
<div>
  {{ form_label(form.username) }}
  {{ form_widget(form.username) }}
  {{ form_errors(form.username) }}
  {{ form_help(form.username) }}
</div>
<div>
  {{ form_label(form.email) }}
  {{ form_widget(form.email) }}
  {{ form_errors(form.email) }}
  {{ form_help(form.email) }}
</div>

<div>
  {{ form_widget(form.is_active) }}
  {{ form_errors(form.is_active) }}
  {{ form_help(form.is_active) }}
</div>

<div>
  {{ form_label(form.plainPassword.first) }}
  {{ form_widget(form.plainPassword.first) }}
  <div class="text-red">{{ form_errors(form.plainPassword.first) }}</div>
  {{ form_help(form.plainPassword.first) }}
</div>
<div>
  {{ form_label(form.plainPassword.second) }}
  {{ form_widget(form.plainPassword.second) }}
  <div class="text-red">{{ form_errors(form.plainPassword.second) }}</div>
  {{ form_help(form.plainPassword.second) }}
</div>

{{ form_end(form) }}
```

But when I edit for example the username in my form and I click on "Update" then I get the error message

> An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO members (username,
>   password, email, is_active) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)' with params ["cat2",
>   "123", "cat@cat.de", "1"]:
>
> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
>   'cat@cat.de' for key 'UNIQ_12A0D2FFE7927C74'

I actually expect the SQL make an UPDATE instead of INSERT...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load the User from the UserRepository::find($id)

```
use App\Repository\UserRepository;
// ...

class MyController
{    
    public function index($id, $slug, 
                          Request $request,
                          UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder,
                          UserRepository $userRepository)
    {

        $item = $userRepository->find($id);

        if(NULL === $item) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('could not find this user.');
        }

        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($item)

        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: He is already doing this according to the code posted in the question.  The new User() line was just a reading test I guess.

Comment: getRepository(User::class) will not work. it should be UserRepository::class right?

Comment: Nope.  getRepository take the entity class name as input and returns the repository for it.  I might add that injecting the user repository will only work in certain conditions.

Comment: This is unfortunately not solving the problem

Comment: the problem occurs in submitting the form, because an INSERT is made instead of an UPDATE

Comment: @Cerad He is a She ;)

Comment: @Jarla Sorry about the gender misunderstanding.  But the real problem is that the code you posted is not the actual code.  You have something else going on.